# CSS: how do I add Twitter Bootstrap to an existing web page with it's own CSS?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm new to Twitter Bootstrap and I guess I don't really full understand the implementation?

How can I add Bootstrap to my existing webpages and the CSS I already have in place for those?

Comment: The question is why you want to add bootstrap? .... If you already have the webpage?.

Comment: It would be nice to use some of the bootstrap framework - buttons and so forth.  Sorry for my ignorance here.

Comment: Also you need to understand what is the purpose of bootstrap it isn't a miracle tool http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/

Comment: If you are determined you can **choose** which parts of Bootstrap to use - http://getbootstrap.com/customize/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to [Bootstrap: Getting Started](http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/)

Find this line

```
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
```

Add it to the `<head></head>` of your existing project.

Start using bootstrap

```
<div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">Well done! You successfully read this important alert message.</div>
```

Comment: does that have any implications for a pre-existing CSS template that I'm already using on the same page?   I thought it wasn't a good practice to link 2 separate CSS files on the same page?

Comment: Absolutely not, the only thing is to keep in mind, not let Bootstrap styles to overwrite yours one. You can construct custom Bootstrap build, if you know what you are going to use.  But from my points of view, you should have any problems.

Comment: thanks that's helpful.   I will keep looking into it.   I like look of Bootstrap elements.  Just wondering what do - use Bootstrap button classes or just standard CSS ones you can find elsewhere.  Maybe it just comes down to personal taste...

Comment: No worries. I've also been using Bootstrap only for buttons for couple of projects. Really handy. Good luck.